# Show Aggregate Data in Laravel Nova

Tags: laravel-nova

I have a model Offer. I want to create a Laravel Resource which shows the aggregate data based on the underlying model by grouping them in years, months like shown below.
[image]

My question is: is it possible to show like this Nova (not a report download)?

Answer (score 1):

Nice question. Yes, it's possible and you should use Nova Linses

https://nova.laravel.com/docs/4.0/lenses/defining-lenses.html